# React Native: How do I completely remove Instabug?

Tags: react-native, instabug

I recently removed Instabug from my React Native 0.53.3 project, but when I run `react-native run-ios` I get a build failure:

```
ld: framework not found Instabug
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

    Ld /Users/danale/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NFIBEngage.app/NFIBEngage normal x86_64
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NFIBEngage.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NFIBEngage.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

How can I completely remove Instabug from my project so it's not looking for it on iOS build?

So far I have completely removed it from `App.js` file, but it's still being referenced in `build.gradle`, `MainActivity.java`, `MainApplication.java`, `settings.gradle`, `project.pbxproj` and `yarn.lock` file. I don't even use `yarn` by the way.

How do I completely clean this up?

Comment: did you try removing podfile and installing it again?

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal, I am not familiar with a podfile and how to remove it and install it, I just know its a Ruby file that has some configuration in it and I don't know what is the connection to `Instabug`. I am also just now noticing it has `platform :ios, '9.0'`, is that a problem when working with Xcode 10.1?

Comment: 1. Remove Instabug entries from Build Settings > Header Search Paths 2. Remove bash script from Build Phases > Strip FrameWorks

Comment: Remove from Framework Search Paths too in Build Settings. You can refer this to undo all the RN link changes [https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-React-Native/blob/48f00cdc86bc98bee8e1f5b553b27e53faf253c5/link.rb]

Comment: @Daniel, Podfile is a specification that describes the dependencies of the targets of one or more Xcode projects. I faced this issue and solved it by removing Instabug from podfile,run pod install, adding Instabug again, and finally running another pod install.

Comment: @Hariks, are there some commands that can automate this? `gradle build` or anything along those lines?

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal, I don't see `Instabug` referenced in the `Podfile` at all, I don't want to add `Instabug` at all, I want my project to forget `Instabug` ever existed and I have tried `pod install` in the past and it is not a recognized command.

Comment: Ideally react-native unlink instabug-reactnative should do the trick

Comment: But It didn't work for me So I manually undid all the react-native link changes

Comment: @Hariks, you helped me solve 99% of it. I also had to remove it all manually, but I still get this particular error: `ld: framework not found Instabug
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. Does this mean its linked somewhere? I tried that `react-native unlink instabug-reactnative` but it did not work.

Comment: Did you clean the project and removed derived data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194267/discussion-between-daniel-and-hariks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `react-native unlink instabug-reactnative` didn't work try removing all react-native link changes manually.

You may refer these pages to remove all references

[Instabug rn link checklist](https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-React-Native/blob/48f00cdc86bc98bee8e1f5b553b27e53faf253c5/link.rb)

[Instabug Documentation](https://docs.instabug.com/docs/react-native-integration)

Clean the project once every reference is removed.(Deleting Xcode derived data may be needed sometimes)